# Execute several commands in one line, and save stdout into a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

In a batch file, I am trying to execute several commands in a single line:

```
start cmd /c "title SomeTitle & python SomeFile.py 1>SomeFile.txt & timeout /t -1"
```

The output file `SomeFile.txt` is created empty, and everything is printed directly to the terminal.

I've tried putting the `python SomeFile.py 1>SomeFile.txt` part within double-quotes.

However, I then get a `The system cannot find the path specified` error.

How can I work around this?

Comment: @jwdonahue: That doesn't work. I also doubt that I need to escape the `&`, because it seems to be doing its job just fine.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the console window manually? It's not working the way you think it is.

Comment: Don't use `start`.

Comment: @jwdonahue: I've tried running the batch script from both a terminal (by entering its name) and from a file explorer (by double-clicking it). It works fine without the `1>SomeFile.txt` part. Adding this part only causes an empty file to be created. The output still goes to the terminal.

Comment: @CatCat: I have several similar lines, which I want to run in parallel (that's why I've added `start` to begin with).

Comment: No, run that line from the console, not the batch file containing it.

Comment: And for testing, use `cmd /k`.

Comment: @jwdonahue: Same results (regarding your previous comment).

Comment: @jwdonahue: with `cmd /k` I just get a new terminal opened (with nothing running in it).

Comment: I guess I will ask the not so obvious.  If you just run: `python SomeFile.py 1>SomeFile.txt` is their output in the text file?

Comment: This works perfectly from the console: `start cmd /k "title SomeTitle & dir 1>SomeFile.txt & timeout /t -1"` but not from a batch file.

Comment: It sounds like SomeFile.py isn't where you think it is - or more likely, your script isn't running where you think it is. If you're running the script as an administrator, the script is currently in `C:\WINDOWS\System32`.

Comment: @jwdonahue - That code works correctly for me in both the terminal and in a script.

Comment: Yes, it turns out to work for me as well. Manual testing is never ideal. So I think the OP's problem lies with the python script.

Comment: @jwdonahue: You are right! In order to print, I use the `logging` module with a `StreamHandler()` instance. I can get the desired behavior by using a `StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` instance instead, but that would hinder other objectives for which I am using the `logging` module to begin with. Thank you!!!